# Can makefile internal macros be used in replacement macros

Tags: makefile

I have been learning how to create make files and understand the basic syntax. Using several online guides and manuals I have cobbled together a working file that I mostly understand however one target line meaning eludes me and I cannot find the guide I used with a line similar to this one. What confuses me is I cannot tell if the internal macro used to represent the current target $@ is being used in a replacement macro? Is that possible?

The following line is what I find confusing:

```
$(OBJ): $(@:=.o)
```

To add proper context I am including my makefile.

```
# Include varialbes for make file acts like similar to the cpp directive
# (non standard to SUS)
include ../build/config.mk

# Define known suffixes
.SUFFIXES: .o .c

# Define include directory macro for header files
INCLUDE = -I../include

# Define source file macro list
SRC =\
    base32.c\
    base64.c\
    change_file_own.c\
    colorize-ls.c\
    comma_list.c\
    datetime.c\
    defs.c\
    error.c\
    escape.c\
    filebuffer.c\
    fileinfo.c\
    filestat.c\
    format.c\
    halt_getopt.c\
    head_tail.c\
    io.c\
    line.c\
    mv-rm.c\
    numbers.c\
    path.c\
    perm.c\
    printf_format.c\ 
    progname.c\ 
    signalinfo.c\
    stack.c\
    uuencode.c\ 
    wrappers.c\ 
#       move.c\

# Define object list to be everything in SRC macro with any instance
# of .c replaced with .o
OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)

# Define final product name
LIB = libutil.a

# Default target including $(LIB) (libutil.a) as a required component
all: $(LIB)

# ???? 
$(OBJ): $(@:=.o)

# SUFFIX rule to transform .c files to .o files
# Compile each precursor c file ($<) and output target object files ($@)
.c.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ -c $<

# Target libutil with component object files
# Run archiver inserting newer than target component object files ($?)
# into and or creating the archive ($@)
$(LIB): $(OBJ)
        $(AR) rcs $@ $?

# Clean up the object files
clean:
        rm -f $(OBJ) $(LIB)
# define fake (non file) target names
# (also might be non-standard to SUS)
.PHONY:
        all clean
```

The config.mk file includes the CFLAGS and the proper paths to the archiver and compiler.

Answer (score 0):

In your `$(OBJ): $(@:=.o)`, the substitution `$(@:=.o)` will expand to nothing.

See the manual [10.5.3 Automatic Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html)

> It’s very important that you recognize the limited scope in which automatic variable values are available:
>   they only have values within the recipe. In particular, you cannot use them anywhere within the target list of a rule;
>   they have no value there and will expand to the empty string. Also, they cannot be accessed directly within the prerequisite list of a rule.
>   A common mistake is attempting to use $@ within the prerequisites list; this will not work.
>   However, there is a special feature of GNU make, secondary expansion (see Secondary Expansion), which will allow automatic variable values to be used in prerequisite lists.

Comment: The line actually does something though. Testing would happen if I removed it I found that my build would not build object files just go straight to building the end library. I am using gnu make so does that mean I am using that secondary expansion feature?

Comment: @ZenoofElea Yes, because `$(@:=.o)` expands to nothing, the line becomes
a list of object-file targets that have no prerequisites. Secondary
expansion does not happen by default. Consult [the GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html). It answers most questions about GNU Make.